# How to insert an obelus or dagger symbol in a text file

Tags: text, unicode

This is really two questions:

(1) [Is there a]/[what is the] compose key sequence for the obelus or dagger symbol?

(2) How can I get `<ctrl><shift><u>` to work, so as to be able to enter unicode characters into a text file?

I can use compose-key sequences to produce symbols such as €, ü, etc., no problema.  So I presume I could use a compose-key sequence to input an obelus or dagger symbol.  But I cannot find any trace of an appropriate sequence.

The link (e.g.) https://unicode-table.com/en/2020/  tells me that the hex code or "code point" for the obelus or dagger symbol is 2020.

So I *should* be able to type

```
   <ctrl><shift><u> 2020
```

to get the symbol I want.  But this doesn't work.  Instructions that I've seen say that I've seen say that when I press `<ctrl><shift><u>` an underscored "u" should appear.  But it doesn't.  Is there any way I can track down what is going wrong, and fix it?

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 with a Mate 1.26.0 desktop.

Thanks.

Comment: Any reason you can't just copy and paste from the page you linked to?

Comment: No idea what you mean by that.

Comment: If you don't know what copy and paste means then there's nothing I can do for you.

Comment: i of course know what copy and paste means.  I do not see what this has to do with the questions that I asked.  These were about the compose key sequence for the obelus or dagger symbol and about how to get <ctrl><shift><u>  to work so that I can make use of hex codes for various symbols.  Copy and paste does not come into the picture.

Comment: I was asking why copy and paste aren't sufficient to solve your problem; it's an honest question.  Most people don't insist on a specific way of doing things if a quick and simple work-around is available.  And I think you asked on the wrong forum, there's nothing about programming in this question - you might try on Ask Ubuntu instead.